# Laravel - create on hasmany not working

Tags: php, laravel

The inserted row `key`,`value` are empty !!

```
\App\Product::find(1)->getProductMeta()->create([
    'key' => 'a key',
     'value' => 'a value'
]);
```

query SQL : 
`` insert into `product_metas` (`product_id`) values (?) ``

Product:

```
function getProductMeta(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\ProductMeta');
}
```

ProductMeta:

`protected $fillable = ['key','value'];`

**Migration**:

```
Schema::create('product_metas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');;

            $table->string('key')->index();
            $table->text('value')->nullable();
        });
```

Comment: Share the table structure of both the models and how are you fetching `$product`?

Comment: @Sandeesh it's here , on update

Comment: If you seek help you need to post the appropriate codes. You haven't posted half of what i asked? Just copy paste your migrations and the controller method.

Comment: post has been updated

Comment: Can you just read what i'm saying? Share the controller code so i can see how you're fetching the `$product`. Since you're using relationship to create, i want to see if the `$product` is a valid model.

Comment: `$product` is a simple , `$product = \App\Product::find(1)` @Sandeesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'v solved my problem with remove function __construct in my Model .

I don't know why i'v made a __construct method !

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. Just try one of these methods to create the relationship item.

Add this to `ProductMeta` model

```
protected $fillable = ['key', 'value', 'product_id'];
```

In your controller do this so that you can get a valid product.

```
$product = Product::findOrFail(1);
```

Then

```
$product->getProductMeta()->create([
    'key' => 'a key',
    'value' => 'a value'
]);
```

Or

```
\App\ProductMeta::create([
    'key' => 'a key',
    'value' => 'a value',
    'product_id' => $product->id
]);
```

Or

```
$productMeta = new \App\ProductMeta;

$productMeta->key = 'a key';
$productMeta->value = 'a value';
$productMeta->product_id = $product->id;

$productMeta->save();
```

Comment: on way 2 : ```SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`store`.`product_metas`, CONSTRAINT `product_metas_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `product_metas` () values ())```

Comment: @danialdezfooli it means the product id doesn't exist on the table. You need to verify if the product exists. That's the reason i used `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`. Run `dd($product);` and check the result.

Comment: product with product->id is exists

Comment: Alright glad it works. I think the reason 2nd method isn't working is because you forgot to update the $fillable property with product_id field

Comment: thanks , no i'v updated `protected $fillable = ['product_id','key','value'];`

Comment: @danialdezfooli may be you can try to define an inverse relationship in the `ProductMeta` model.

Answer (score -2):

you have to make relation in both models eg. Product model and admin model

for example you say in your `product model`

```
public function admin(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'admin_id');
  }
```

and in your `admin model`

```
public function product(){
       return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

like this both tables and models will be related to each other.

PS: I don't know your exact model and tables so i just assume admins as publishers and products as post you can change it to your table names.

Comment: it's not my ansewr